# Theme logo not changing in magento 2 custom theme

Tags: magento2, theme, logo

I had created custom theme in Magento 2 and parent theme as `Magento/blank`. In my custom theme I have changed logo for my theme. I had declared the theme logo in the `app/design/frontend/Prasan/Sanku/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo_new.png</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">300</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">300</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

After writing this code I had cleared following files `var/cache` , `var/generation`, `var/view_preprocessed` and even `pub/static/` but still the theme logo not changed.

I had uploaded `logo_new.png` at `app/design/frontend/Prasan/Sanku/web/images/`

Comment: You can read more here: http://www.boolfly.com/create-new-magento-2-theme/

Comment: official Magento doc: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html#theme_logo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to declare in

**app/design/frontend/Prasan/Sanku/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

Comment: thanks Bilal Usean. its a small think i missed. thanks again.

Comment: @PradeepSanku, you didn't miss anything. Magento's documentation is stated as your original question, but their documentation is wrong.

Comment: Is it the same for Magento 2.3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 uses an SVG logo by default, and it will find yours automatically if you put it in your theme directory at: web/images/logo.svg.

You may also need to specify the dimensions in: Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml.

Example:

```
   <body>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <!-- Set numbers as needed -->
            <argument name="logo_width" xsi:type="number">180</argument>
            <argument name="logo_height" xsi:type="number">75</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```